# How can I properly use variable month columns in a PowerBI query?

Tags: powerbi, m

I have a performance monitoring table in which users are listed vertically and then months are listed across the header.  These months are dynamically generated on a 12-month rolling window.  At the beginning of each month, one month falls off the back of the query and another appears at the front.  After beginning of month, I get the following error until I manually re-run the report:
`The '<#MONTH>' column does not exist in the rowset.`
Where `'<#MONTH>'` is the month that gets dropped off, e.g. if it is Sept 2019, it would be 'August 2018'.

I tried adding a window to the query that moved the start of the query ahead a day to try to eliminate the perceived race condition. This did not work.

Here is the M query I have currently:

```
let
    Source = US_TOTALS,
    #"Appended Query" = Table.SelectRows(Table.Combine({Source, CA_TOTALS}), each [DATELASTFULFILLMENT] >= #"This Year"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Appended Query",{"SALESMAN", "RegionName", "DATELASTFULFILLMENT", "Total Sales", "Customer", "GROUP"}),
    #"Inserted Start of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "StartOfMonth", each Date.StartOfMonth([DATELASTFULFILLMENT]), type date),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Inserted Start of Month",{"SALESMAN", "RegionName", "DATELASTFULFILLMENT", "Total Sales", "StartOfMonth", "GROUP", "Customer"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns1",{"Customer"}),
    #"Date One" = Date.AddMonths(Date.StartOfMonth(Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),1)),1),
    #"Date Two" = Date.AddYears(Date.AddMonths(Date.StartOfMonth(Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),1)),0),-1),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each [DATELASTFULFILLMENT] < Date.AddMonths(Date.StartOfMonth(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())),1) and [DATELASTFULFILLMENT] >= Date.AddYears(Date.AddMonths(Date.StartOfMonth(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())),0),-1)),
    //#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each Date.From([DATELASTFULFILLMENT]) < #"Date One" and Date.From([DATELASTFULFILLMENT]) >= #"Date Two"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"SALESMAN", "RegionName", "StartOfMonth", "GROUP"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Total Sales]), type number}}),
    #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"SALESMAN", "RegionName", "GROUP", "StartOfMonth", "Total"}),
    #"Inserted Month Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns2", "Month Name", each Date.MonthName([StartOfMonth]), type text),
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month Name", "Year", each Date.Year([StartOfMonth]), type number),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Inserted Year", {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Month Name", "Year"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Month"),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"StartOfMonth", "GROUP"}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns2", {"SALESMAN", "Month", "RegionName"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Total]), type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows1",{{"SALESMAN", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Columns" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[Month]), "Month", "Total", List.Sum),
    Columns = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Columns"),2),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Columns",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Columns),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",List.Transform(Columns, each {_, Currency.Type })),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"SALESMAN"},USER_MAPPING_COMBINED,{"USERNAME"},"USER_MAPPING_COMBINED",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded USER_MAPPING" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "USER_MAPPING_COMBINED", {"NAME"}, {"NAME"})
in
    #"Expanded USER_MAPPING"
```

Expected Results:
The query refreshes as normal

Actual Results:
The query errors with `The '<#MONTH>' column does not exist in the rowset.`
Where `'<#MONTH>'` is the month that gets dropped off, e.g. if it is Sept 2019, it would be 'August 2018'.

screenshot for reference:

[image: Salesman Query]

Comment: @RyanB. The error is on scheduled refresh, so what I'm asking is how do I fix it without renaming? This is a dynamic report.

Comment: @RyanB. So basically, the gist of what I'm getting is that PowerBI is incapable of doing this.

Comment: Yuk.  I definitely didn't say that.

Comment: @RyanB. What it seems like the above is saying is telling me to take the dynamic portion of this rowset and make it static.  Am I wrong there?

Comment: I can't see a reference to a specific month name in your code at all. Which row of code causes the error? When you step through the action panel from top to bottom, which one throws the error?

Comment: @teylyn That's kind of my point I have made this all dynamic.  Unfortunately, the Azure service doesn't give you a line number (unhelpful). It just points to this query.

Comment: What is the exact error, without masking the month name? It may well be in a different query that this query builds on. Nothing in the M you posted refers to an August or September, so it is definitely not in this query.

Comment: @teylyn `Data source error: The 'August 2018' column does not exist in the rowset. Table: Salesman`

Comment: The other queries this is based on feed the other sections of my report.  if the error were there, it would surely break those too right?

Comment: Nothing Directly references it, but it is referenced, albeit dynamically.  the references would come in at the columns line which gets the month names.

Comment: And what is that? What is `he columns line which gets the month names`? I don't understand that. If you step through the query in the Query Editor (not the Advanced Editor), by clicking each step, starting with the top one, i.e. `Source`, at what row does the error get thrown?

Comment: @teylyn it doesn't. This is thrown on the scheduled refresh.

Comment: So how do you know it is this query that has the problem? It doesn't refer to any column `August 2018`. You need to work on the query that has that column.

Comment: As has been stated before, none of the other queries has this issue.  As to how I know, it is stated very mainly in the error.  @teylyn Data source error: The 'August 2018' column does not exist in the rowset. --> Table: Salesman <--

Comment: What data source are you referring to in your question when you mention the 12 months rolling window?

Comment: The column does exist there, it just isn't explicitly called out, as stated before.  This code,`Columns = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Columns"),2)`   gets all of the month column names.  This is the part that would contain that name at some point.

Comment: I think you need to simplify the problem to the fact that you pivot data in Power Query and then need to work with different column names in the result of the pivot. Post a data sample so that we can recreate the problem. This needs to be in your question, so this long trail of comments can be removed.

Comment: I start to think the problem is related to sequence of updating. When you run it manually, all works. Can it be the other tables are up to date and are ok. Now you do your scheduled update, because it is dynamic, Power-Bi does not know which query to do first. If it takes the dynamic query first it throws error. I would create one query from start to finish where I have control on what comes first/last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to take a second swing at this.  If I'm way off base, I apologize.  But let me bring out an example to simulate your error.

```
let
    Seed = Number.Mod(Number.Round(Time.Second(DateTime.LocalNow())), 7) + 1,
    Source = List.Generate(()=> Seed, each _ < Seed + 6, each _ + 1),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"MonthNumbers"}, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "MonthNames", each Date.MonthName(#date(2019, [MonthNumbers], 1))),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[MonthNames]), "MonthNames", "MonthNumbers", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

So, this creates a table that looks like so:

[image]

But every single second, the frame shifts by a month.  So if you refresh the preview every second, you'll see the frame slide Jan-Jun, Feb-Jul, Mar-Aug... when December is the last month in the window, it skips back to the Jan-Jun.  The point is, the columns are changing.

Now you try to load this model.  It does not work!

[image]

From the time you create the model with one column set, to the time it takes to load the column set, those columns have been changed and so one of the columns isn't there any more.  This is like when your month changes.  When you go in and load manually, you'll update your model and things will work fine until the next change in columns.  But when you're doing it with the scheduled load, that doesn't update the model, it just tries to load the data and runs into this column mismatch.

So, how do we fix it without losing this dynamic naming?  Let's look at that pivot... what if we don't do it and leave our power query looking like this?

[image]

Now the column names won't change when we load it into the model.  We create a matrix visualization like so, and do some refreshes:

[image]
[image]
[image]

No errors, nice dynamic headers.

So, that's the approach that I think you need.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Per comment, this answer shows how to deal with a source that comes with changing column names over time, which is not the problem the asker has.

@RyanB is correct. The right approach here is to do your crosstab layout in reports rather than in data model. The right way, in general, to deal with things that change is to reify these as data, rather than as schema.

**Original post below**

---

You're looking for the 'Unpivot other columns' transform:

[image: unpivot other columns]

1. Select the columns whose names **do not** change.
2. Use 'Unpivot other columns' transform
3. Rename columns
4. Deal with months as a single month column

Make sure this comes before any steps that depend on the changing column names.

Here are two sample queries that are identical in code except for the source, which has differently named columns:

```
// query1
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("RU85FsQgCL2LdQoWUTiLL8VkJve/QliSTKF8/oK4VsO2tY8fpLyEe1aWKm3fVgvpiF7SBNLZZulQQLrD9LK339I6mAOYpoJBo5tmUOgUYNr7YwfTiUwShA/VyL/wnufhyMRqv1oHRswTJANNBshGAWN63edNkf41j4GJvzseMn67Xw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Somethingstatic = _t, #"May-2019" = _t, #"Jun-2019" = _t, #"Jul-2019" = _t, #"Aug-2019" = _t]),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"ID", "Somethingstatic"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Month"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Value", Int64.Type}, {"ID", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"


// query 2
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("RU85FsQgCL2LdQoWUTiLL8VkJve/QliSTKF8/oK4VsO2tY8fpLyEe1aWKm3fVgvpiF7SBNLZZulQQLrD9LK339I6mAOYpoJBo5tmUOgUYNr7YwfTiUwShA/VyL/wnufhyMRqv1oHRswTJANNBshGAWN63edNkf41j4GJvzseMn67Xw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Somethingstatic = _t, #"Jun-2019" = _t, #"Jul-2019" = _t, #"Aug-2019" = _t, #"Sep-2019" = _t]),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"ID", "Somethingstatic"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Month"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Value", Int64.Type}, {"ID", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: From his Power Query, you can see that he is deliberately pivoting the results on month.  Isn't it better to recommend that he not pivot at all, rather than "undoing" the work of the pivot step with an unpivot?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I missed that in scanning the code and thought it was a source issue instead. Serves me right for practicing speed-reading on code (: Thanks